# Is (1,1,1,...) a part of hilbert space

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

In linear algebra and its application professor Gilbert Strang writes:

"A much better idea is to keep the familiar definition of length, using a sum of squares, and to include only those vectors that have a ***finite length***:

**Length squared** = $||v||^2 = v_1^2 +v_2^2 + v_3^2 + ...$

The infinite series must converge to a finite sum. **this leaves (1, 1/2, 1/3,...) but not (1,1,1,...)**. The vectors with finite length can be added $(\|v + w\| \le \|v\| + \|w\|)$ and multiplied by scalars, so they form a vector space. It is the celebrated  ***hilbert  space***."

this leaves (1, 1/2, 1/3,...) but not (1,1,1,...)? does this make sense. to me partial sums of this (1,1,1,...) do not converge

Comment: By "this leaves" the author means "this includes."  Can also think of it as in "this leaves (1, 1/2, 1/3, ...) as an element of the space but (1,1,1,...) is not an element of the space."

Comment: I've just noticed that Gilbert is a letter off of Hilbert.

Comment: It's a language thing. You start with the space of all sequences, and then _remove_ those that have infinite length. You're _left with_ elements like $(1, 1/2,1/3, \ldots)$. In other words, the process of removing the infinite elements _leaves_ $(1, 1/2,1/3, \ldots)$ behind, or it _leaves_ $(1, 1/2,1/3, \ldots)$ alone, or it _leaves_ $(1, 1/2,1/3, \ldots)$ be, or whatever else you want to use to complete that phrase.

Comment: @tilper : the partial sums of (1,1/2,1/3,...) diverge away to infinity as well.

Comment: @Arthur : the partial sums of (1,1/2,1/3,...) diverge away to infinity as well

Comment: But we're not looking at the partial sums. We're looking at partial sums of the _square_ of the terms in the sequence. And $1+\frac14+\frac19+\cdots$ converges just fine.

Comment: @arthur: what about "The infinite series must converge to a finite sum". maybe i can answer myself? he is defining sum to be the sum of squares? confirm

Comment: It does say $\|v\|^2 = v_1^2 +v_2^2 + v_3^2 + \cdots$ right up there in your question. You even typed it in _yourself_ a little over an hour ago (with a minor correction just now). Those are the squares of the terms of the sequence that are added together, yes.

Comment: @arthur: that was a typo which i corrected in the question. it is ||v||^2 = ....

Comment: That typo doesn't matter. It's the right-hand side that is important, and the terms there all have little $^2$'s on them. That means that you square each element before you add them together.

Comment: @Arthur: yes got it

Comment: What Arthur said.

Answer (score 2):

What you've described is an **example** of a Hilbert space. Our vectors need not be lists of coordinates, and our measurement of length doesn't need to be the usual sum of squares (that is, we can define different *inner products*). However: you can indeed say that $(1,1,\dots)$ fails to be an element of the Hilbert space that you've described.